# Площадки для размещения android-приложений

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Не так давно гугл заблокировал мой аккаунт разработчика в Play Console. Читал, что попытки регистрации новых аккаунтов приводят к новым блокировкам, поэтому имеет смысл регистрировать аккаунты только на каких-то знакомых, т.е. чтобы в новом аккаунте никоим образом не содержалась моя личная информация. Такой способ не совсем удобен, поэтому встал вопрос: какие существуют площадки, кроме Google Play, на которых имеет смысл размещать приложения? Заработком на приложениях из Google Play являлся показ рекламы в этих приложениях, поэтому при выборе площадки одним из главных критериев является количество пользователей этой площадки.

Comment: [Альтернативные Android маркеты](http://infoshell.ru/blog/alternativnye-magaziny-android-prilozhenii/)

Comment: а за что блокирнули то?

Comment: @rjhdby REASON FOR TERMINATION: Prior violations of the Developer Program Policies and Developer Distribution Agreement by this or associated accounts as outlined in previous emails sent to the registered email address(es) of the Publisher account(s).

Comment: если приложение размещено с целью заработка (реклама, внутренние покупки и т.п), то реальных альтернатив - нет. На остальных площадках вместе взятых, у вас кол-во установок будет меньше, чем на Google Play